# What are the differences between "Premium Beta" and "Standard Beta"?

Tags: elite-dangerous

The new [Elite: Dangerous store](https://store.zaonce.net/) launched yesterday, allowing the purchase of a variety of packages including;

- Preorder Elite: Dangerous
- Standard Beta
- Premium Beta

[image]

What are the differences between "Premium Beta" and "Standard Beta"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences between "[Standard](https://store.zaonce.net/elite-dangerous-standard-beta.html)" and "[Premium](https://store.zaonce.net/elite-dangerous-premium-beta.html)" beta are a throwback to the original Kickstarter campaign, in that Frontier are going to be running two rounds of private beta before opening the game up to the public.

Premium beta will get you into the first round of beta testing, which is intended to be started in February at this time. Standard beta will get you into the second around of beta testing, which will start sometime after that.

Both packages will provide you with a digital release of the game once it is released. The Premium beta package also includes the [Expansion Pass](https://store.zaonce.net/elite-dangerous-expansion-pass.html), which will give you access to all future downloadable content free of charge - like a season pass.